# Sum the parameters in javascript constructor and return total

Tags: javascript

If I have a constructor and want to sum the parameter values and output to an inner method, I thought I could do the following:

```
function Stats(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c; 
    this.d = d; 
    this.e = e; 
    this.f = f;
    var total = 0;
    var array = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
    var len = array.length;
    this.sum = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            total += array[i];
        }
        return total;
    };
}
var output = new Stats(10, 25, 5, 84, 8, 44);
console.log(output);
```

When looking at the console 'total' is 0.

I'm sure I have completely failed with my logic, so if you have suggestions how to improve this (as well as the sum) I'd love to read them.

Comment: `var total` is declared outside the `sum` method so the first time you call `sum` you will get the correct value, and the next time you call `sum` you will get double the correct value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be abbreviated.

```
function Stats(var_args) {
  var sum = 0;
  // The arguments pseudo-array allows access to all the parameters.
  for (var i = 0, n = arguments.length; i < n; ++i) {
    // Use prefix + to coerce to a number so that += doesn't do
    // string concatenation.
    sum += +arguments[i];
  }
  // Set the sum property to be the value instead of a method
  // that computes the value.
  this.sum = sum;
}

var output = new Stats(10, 25, 5, 84, 8, 44);
// You can use a format string to see the object and a specific value.
console.log("output=%o, sum=%d", output, output.sum);
```

Comment: Thanks Mike...this is actually what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
function Stats(){
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The Arguments variable contains all arguments of the function in an array.

Not sure what you wanted to achieve there but I thought it might be useful looking at your variable stack there

Answer (score 1):

You have to call sum - output is the object:

```
console.log(output.sum());
```

and to improve your class i would go on something more general to not limit the num of my params if all i want to do is to sum them:

```
    function Stats() {
        this.total = (function(args){
            var total = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                total += args[i];
            }

            return total;
        })(arguments);
     }
var output = new Stats(10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10,100,24,1000);

console.log(output.total);
```

Comment: Why are you running the loop inside an IIFE?

Comment: it's self execute function so it will run when I create the class and not have to call function again after creation

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you remove the function, and keep the loop, changing `args` to `arguments` and `self` to `this`, you'll get the exact same behavior.

Comment: ...same with your updated code. The extra function plays no useful role.

Comment: I'm learning this stuff, so this really helps. Thanks, Adidi.

Answer (score 1):

Available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/pKtTx/)

```
function Stats(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
    this.f = f;

    this.sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function (x, y) {
        return x + y;
    }, 0);

}

var output = new Stats(10, 25, 5, 84, 8, 44);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You don't need `.slice()`. Just do `Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, func...)`

Answer (score 1):

Optimized version that, I think, does what you wanted:

```
function Stats() {
    var _arguments = arguments;
    this.sum = function() {
        var i = _arguments.length;
        var result = 0;
        while (i--) {
            result += _arguments[i];
        }
        return result;
    };
}
var output = new Stats(10, 25, 5, 84, 8, 44);
console.log(output.sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you have written the code, you should be doing

```
console.log(output.sum());
```

In order to get the desired output